# C# array access performance with loop delimited by readonly boundaries?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, compilation

I am wondering whether the C# compiler is (or *should be*) offering performance optimization on array accesses when iterating over a provable safe range. In particular, my interest lies in the use of `readonly` variables.

```
public class MySegment
{
    private readonly float[] _array;
    private readonly int _offset;
    private readonly float _count;

    public MySegment(float[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        _array = array;
        _offset = offset;
        _count = count;
    }

    public float Sum()
    {
        var sum = 0f;
        for (int i = _offset; i < _offset + _count; i++)
        {
            sum += _array[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

In the example above, it is provable that the variable `i` is not overflowing the array with a test outside the loop itself; hence, I would expect only a single boundary check to be done at the *beginning* of the loop, not one check per iteration.

Can someone shed light on this case? Are my performance expectations correct?

Comment: I can't offer any evidence here, but I suspect you're ask a bit too much from the runtime.

Comment: It would certainly be the JIT doing this rather than the C# compiler though.

Comment: Indeed. JS is right. Readonly does not imply compile-time invariance.